# Filepond - how to use onreorderfiles just when event drop is activated?

Tags: javascript, filepond

Im using filepond to upload some photos and I have this part of code to drag and drop.

```
this.galleryUpload.onreorderfiles = (origin, target) => {
    if (target >= array.length) {
        var k = target - array.length + 1;
        while (k--) {
            array.push(undefined);
        }
    }
    array.splice(target, 0, array.splice(origin, 1)[0]);
};
```

It's working fine. When the event finish up, the element change the position on my `array`, but the point is that even when I do not drop the file while I'm dragging, it change the position on the array. In theory when do not drop Im not reordering the photos.

Do you know how can I deal with that? I just want to change the position on my array when I drop the photo.